# How to check if SQLite row is empty

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I have the following which only inserts to column `two` if the value is empty:

```
UPDATE name 
SET one=?,
    two=COALESCE(two, ?),
    three=? 
WHERE id = ?
```

However, this only works if column `two` if the value is `null`. How can I get this to work if it is either `NULL OR an empty string`.

It should **always** insert to `one` and `three`. It should only insert to `two` if it is NULL or empty

I am using SQLite with PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "empty" you mean an empty string, you can use `nullif()`:

```
two = COALESCE(NULLIF(two, ''), ?)
```

The more general solution is a `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store empty strings in `TEXT` columns.
Update the table to replace all empty strings with `NULL`s:

```
UPDATE name
SET two = NULL
WHERE TRIM(two) = ''
```

Now you can use your query, which is correct and in any other query you only need to check for `NULL`.

Comment: @jefiwo the notion of NULL is that it represents *missing information* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)), while an empty string is a valid string value. Also, just to be practical. Do you want to check 2 (or more) conditions: if the column is NULL, or if it is empty, or if it consists of spaces?